# Несколько вопросов по ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Здравствуйте.

Вот решил самостоятельно немного освоить ASP.NET. Начал осваивать по одной там методичке, она писалась под более старую Visual Studio, поэтому, быть может, идут несовпадения...

Вот например там я дошел до пункта: "Выберите св-во Style", так у меня такого св-ва нету в чистом документе ни на одном элементе, поэтому пришлось что-то там искать в Format и этот далее упоминаемый Style Builder... В этом же Style Buildere там есть по методичке "Выберите слева Background, выберите опцию Transparent" - опции Transparent у меня нету...

Я уже не говорю о том, что там есть пункт: "Выберите все эти 4 элемента управления (там texboxы и т.п.) с помощью Shift и в св-вах в меню Layout выберите Position - Absolute". Ну во-первых: у меня оно выделилось с помощью CTRL только, ну и самое главное: никакого св-ва Position со значением Absolute я не нашёл.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться и почему столько расхождений со старой Visual Studio?

Понимаю, что вопрос, наверное, очень простой для профессионалов, но я только этот ASP.NET начал осваивать сам, а там уже не успел и страницу текста прочитать такие расхождения... Вот и хотелось бы разобраться, а то сам не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, надо изучать версию asp.net  хотя бы  2.х. Существенной разницы не будет между ней и последней версией.

Во-вторых, переходя с  2008 студии на 2010, никаких проблем не ощутил.

В-третьих, бросайте вы эти методички и читайте(если дружите с английским):

- ASP.NET 4 Unleashed
- Apress - Beginning ASP.NET 4 in C.Sharp 2010

Если не дружите:

- Мак-Дональд М., Шпушта М.  ASP.NET 3.5 с примерами на C#2008
- Дино Экспозито. ASP.NET 2.0 Базовый курс_(лично я учился по этой)

Ещё есть довольно неплохие курсы Гайдара Магданурова, очень доходчиво обьясняет, на интуите есть его видео.

Comment: Позвольте прокомментировать некоторые моменты. \n
"Во-первых, надо изучать версию asp.net хотя бы 2.х" - у меня последняя. \n
"Во-вторых, переходя с 2008 студии на 2010, никаких проблем не ощутил."
Там в методичке не 2008, там в лучшем случае 2005ю \n
"В-третьих, бросайте вы эти методички и читайте(если дружите с английским):"
Дело не в английском, подобно тому, как и не в методичках. Просто по одному из заданий нужно сначала выполнить упражнение по методичке, чем я и занимаюсь.

Comment: Насчёт версии асп вы меня не поняли, я имел ввиду учить по книге 2ой и выше вресии, ибо расхождений мало.
 А чтобы не было таких досадных расхождений как у вас,я и посоветовал, нормальную, проверенную временем литературу.
 И насчёт языка, поверьте это очень важно при возможности учить именно на английском.
 PS клавишей ctrl вы выбираете элементы по одному, при помощи shift, нажав на первый и последний элемнт в списке вы выделите все!

Comment: @И насчёт языка, поверьте это очень важно при возможности учить именно на английском.@
1. Что вы имеете введу?
2. Хм... Ну у нас как бы половина предметов вообще в ВУЗе на англ. ведется..
"PS клавишей ctrl вы выбираете элементы по одному, при помощи shift, нажав на первый и последний элемнт в списке вы выделите все!"
Спасибо конечно, но я не настолько ламер)
Быть может вы сможете мне подсказать где выбрать это Absolute позиционирование и почему при выборе элемента Document я не нахожу напрямую св-во Style(где по нажатии должен открываться StyleBuilder)?

Comment: Просто напишите руками атрибут  <имяКонтрола ID="..." runat="server" Style="position: absolute;" />

Comment: Спасибо. Хм.. Странно.. Всёравно норм не двигается.

Comment: Если вы хотите перетаскивать с тулбокса в дизайнер использую абсолютное позиционирование то нужно сделать следующее Tools->Options->Html Disigner->Css Styling и там поставить в самом низу галочку на "Change position to absolute...." но на самом деле всё что он будет делать это добавлять вышеописаный атрибут

Answer (score 0):

Советую не заморачиваться с книгами, а изучать технологию по вебкастам. В частности, это можно делать на http://www.techdays.ru. Плюс, опять же, советую изучать ASP.NET MVC 3 и новый движок Razor.